# Multiple path in Exclude Depot Path in Jenkins using P4 Plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

I have a perforce workspace which contains multiple modules. I want to create single job for each module in jenkins and want this job to get triggered only if this module code changes.

For this to work I have to exclude other modules depot path using P4 Plugin feature which is "Exclude changes from depot path". Here when i give single depot path ,it works fine but when i give multiple depot path using space as a separator then this module get trigger even if the check-ed in code satisfy the filter path.

So My query is how should I mention multiple depot path against "Exclude changes from depot path"  Is there any specific deliminator I have to use.

Note : I am using latest P4 plugin : 1.4.6 , latest jenkins build

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged an issue? You can do this via the plugin page https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin